# Wordpress Taxonomy Category Filter

Tags: wordpress, list, post, categories, taxonomy

Hi my english very very bad sorry:)wordpress custom post `name=realestate` taxonmy `name=realestate_cat` created.I want created a post list of the content based on taxonomy categories
My codes

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'realestate', 
        'taxonomy' => 'realestate_cat',
        'cat' => 2,
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    ?>
```

This code does not work...

---

My function code:

```
function themes_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'emlak_kategori',  //The name of the taxonomy. Name should be in slug form (must not contain capital letters or spaces).
        'emlak',         //post type name
        array(
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'label'             => 'Emlak Kategorileri',  //Display name
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => array(
                    'slug'          => 'emlak', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
                    'with_front'    => false // Don't display the category base before
                    )
            )
        );
}
add_action( 'init', 'themes_taxonomy');
function filter_post_type_link( $link, $post) {
    if ( $post->post_type != 'emlak' )
        return $link;

    if ( $cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'emlak_kategori' ) )
        $link = str_replace( '%emlak_kategori%', array_pop($cats)->slug, $link );
    return $link;
}
add_filter('post_type_link', 'filter_post_type_link', 10, 2);
add_action( 'init', 'register_themepost', 20 );
function register_themepost() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'Emlaklar', 'catchthemes_custom_post','catchthemes' ),
        'singular_name' => _x( 'Theme', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'add_new' => _x( 'Emlak Ekle', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'add_new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Bir Emlak Ekle', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'edit_item' => _x( 'Emlak İlanını Düzenleyin', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'new_item' => _x( 'Yeni Emlak İlanı', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'view_item' => _x( 'Emlak İlanınızı Önizleyin', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'search_items' => _x( 'Emlak Ara', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'not_found' => _x( 'Henüz Emlak İlanı Eklenmemiş', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => _x( 'Çöp Kutusunda Birşey Bulunamadı', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'parent_item_colon' => _x( 'Parent ThemePost:', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
        'menu_name' => _x( 'Emlaklar', 'catchthemes_custom_post', 'catchthemes' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'description' => 'Emlaklar',
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'post-formats', 'custom-fields' ),
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag','emlak_kategori'),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'show_in_menu' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'menu_icon' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/maidenstower.png',
        'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'query_var' => true,
        'can_export' => true,
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'emlak/%emlak_kategori%','with_front' => FALSE),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => 'emlak',
        'capability_type' => 'post'
    );
    register_post_type( 'emlak', $args );//max 20 charachter cannot contain capital letters and spaces
}
```

Comment: what is your taxonomy term ?

Comment: I do not really know your level of wp / php ... but the specific code that you posted , if stays like that will display nothing . did you try for example to add `the_title()` or `echo get_the_ID()` ? ( and excuse me if I state the obvious .. but on SE you can never know..)

Answer (score 0):

you must try with the taxonomy term like below

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'=> 'realestate', 
        'taxonomy' => 'realestate_cat',
        'term'=>'your taxonomy term'
        'cat' => 2,
    );
    query_posts( $args );
    if (have_posts()) :  while (have_posts()) : the_title (); the_post();
    ?>
```